# Which is the logic behind a Rails login?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, authentication, ruby-on-rails-5

How does Rails manage the authorizations of users?

Supposing i have a database on MySQL, how Rails give a user on the internet the authorization to create resources or to delete them and so to modify the content of a table?

Is there maybe a series of "`GRANT`" or "`REVOKE`" when creating a User? Or their actions are simply controlled by the programmer and each user has no authorization?

This question can be stupid, but i don't have a lot of experience.

Answer (score 0):

Authorization can be achieved in Rails applications by using gems such as Pundit https://github.com/varvet/pundit or Cancancan.

There is no role-based authorization happening by default.

Comment: Is it the same for Devise?

Comment: Devise is an authentication gem which is different to authorization. In plain terms, devise works out who you are. Pundit works out whether you're allowed to be where you are.

Comment: Ok, but how a user can modify (update) or create a record? Where/when he has taken these authorization?